# Convert .NET datetime to SQlite datetime

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've tried to query with a datetime in C#, database : SQlite.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select * from PhieuNhap where NgayNhap=$NgayNhap";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("$NgayNhap", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ngayNhap;
```

ngayNhap is a DateTime type.

But it seems doesn't work this way .

Comment: c# does bit have a DateTime type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get an exception or is the value just ignored?

One thing you could try is not setting the parameter type manually:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select * from PhieuNhap where NgayNhap=$NgayNhap";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("$NgayNhap", ngayNhap));
```